# How to do multiline UILabel in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, multiline

I'm dynamically populating the title (UILabel). Sometime it's bit too long and IOS squeeze the font to fit in the width. Is there a way to do multiline with using same font size?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Set [`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW8) to NO and [`numberOfLines`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW19) to 0.

### [numberOfLines Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW19)

> This property controls the maximum number of lines to use in order to
>   fit the label’s text into its bounding rectangle. The default value
>   for this property is 1. **To remove any maximum limit, and use as many
>   lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.**
>
> If you constrain your text using this property, any text that does not
>   fit within the maximum number of lines and inside the bounding
>   rectangle of the label is truncated using the appropriate line break
>   mode.
>
> When the receiver is resized using the sizeToFit method, resizing
>   takes into account the value stored in this property. For example, if
>   this property is set to 3, the sizeToFit method resizes the receiver
>   so that it is big enough to display three lines of text.

You may additionally want to specify the [`lineBreakMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW16) unless the default [`UILineBreakModeWordWrap`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UILineBreakModeWordWrap) is suitable for what you want.

Comment: Worth noting that `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` is deprecated since iOS 6.0, replaced by `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`

Comment: No need to set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `NO` - **Default is `NO`**

Answer (score 6):

Use `UILabel` properties as below :

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;  
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you set the `numberOfLines` to 0, and the `.lineBreakMode` to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` in code, or the equivalents if your label is defined in IB.

Answer (score 2):

I just used LineBreak mode to Truncate Tail and setNumberOfLines to 0 and its working for me.
the label is of multiline now.

Comment: Set the Autoshrink to minimum font size. and check the tighten letter spacing.

Comment: This is essential! Word wrap *doesn't* do it, you must set a truncate mode